# maximal elementary abelian p-subgroups of finite groups of Lie type

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a simple algebraic group over an algebraically closed field k of characteristic $p$. Let $G(\mathbb{F}_{p^r})$ be the corresponding finite group of Lie type. Is it true that every maximal elementary abelian $p$-subgroup of $G(\mathbb{F}_{p^r})$ can be written as $H(\mathbb{F}_{p^r})$ where $H$ is a commutative algebraic subgroup of $G$? If not, is it known to be true under any circumstance?

Comment: This is closely related to a couple of earlier questions raised here, including http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188092/abelian-p-subgroups-of-e-6q/188176#188176.   Note the references to earlier work of Mal'cev and Vdovin, and the detailed discussion of $p$-rank for simple groups of Lie type in Number 3 (section 3.3) of *The Classification of Finite Simple Groups* by Gorenstein-Lyons-Solomon (AMS, 1998).

Comment: I'm inclined to think that the answer is *yes*, because one can regard any *finite* subgroup as an algebraic subgroup... If you want $H$ to be *connected*, then things are much more difficult...

Comment: Thanks so much Jim and Nick! I just got the book you said and I am attacking it.